# Can't get Row Click Handler for GWT CellTable

Tags: gwt

I'm trying to setup a Row-click handler for the GWT CellTable (GWT 2.1). The stackoverflow post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5792048/adding-clickhandler-to-row-in-celltable-in-gwt) indicates that you should be able to get the type of handler using:

```
boolean isClick = "click".equals(event.getType())
```

But `event.getType()` doesn't return a string, so the evaluation isn't working. The CellPreviewEvent is working, but it fires lots of events (not just click), and I'm having a hard time figuring out how to only get the click events..

Has anyone found a solution to this? (Or can explain what I'm doing wrong in following the post)

Comment: I've also tried - "click".equals(event.getType().getClass().getName().toString();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to get the native event associated with the GwtEvent:

```
"click".equals(event.getNativeEvent().getType());
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a `NoSelectionModel` and listen to `SelectionChange` events.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a check column with a celltable. You can handle selection change event like the sample below.

```
selectionModel.addSelectionChangeHandler(new Handler() {
@Override
public void onSelectionChange(SelectionChangeEvent event) {
    Contentshort objSelected = selectionModel.getSelectedObject();
if (selectionModel.isSelected(objSelected)) {
    Window.alert("selected");
} else {
    Window.alert("deselected");
}               
}       
});
```